# Does releasing a UIView release all its subviews?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiview

If I have a `UIView`, and I add an allocated subview into it (in this case the `UIImageView`), when I release the `UIView`, will `UIImageView` also be released?

I set up my view and a subview like this:

```
UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
UIImage *myImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

// This is the subview:
UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
imageView.image=myImage;

[view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

Now, when I call:

```
[view removeFromSuperview];
[view release];
```

Will the allocated imageView also be released, or should I remove it by removing all of the view's subviews?

Any insight on this topic is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.  The UIView "owns" the subviews so it releases them when it is itself dealloc'd.

Comment: ... which isn't to say the subviews are themselves dealloc'd, since they may be retained by something else (or several somethings else).